# Translating MySQL CREATE TABLE syntax to Postgresql

Tags: mysql, database, postgresql

I'm new to MySQL, and would like to understand the following CREATE TABLE code:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS label_gtin (
  LABEL_ID int NOT NULL,
  GTIN_CD varchar(13) NOT NULL,
  KEY LABEL_ID (LABEL_ID,GTIN_CD)
);
```

Specifically, I'd like to understand what "KEY LABEL_ID (LABEL_ID,GTIN_CD)" does, and translate this to Postgresql.

Would appreciate any help. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Have you tried reading [the documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table.html)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can write given CREATE TABLE code in postgresql as shown :

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS label_gtin (
  LABEL_ID integer NOT NULL,
  GTIN_CD varchar(13) NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT LABEL_ID PRIMARY KEY(LABEL_ID,GTIN_CD)
);
```

`Key` (`PRIMARY KEY` in postgresql) is a Primary Key constraint on one or more columns 
whose combination is unic for records in table.

Syntax: `CONSTRAINT <Constraint Name> PRIMARY KEY(<Column1>[,<Column2>,<Column3>,...])`

`IF NOT EXISTS`: Do not throw an error if a relation with the same name already exists. A notice is issued in this case. Note that there is no guarantee that the existing relation is anything like the one that would have been created.

you can Refer this link for details : http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createtable.html